# Why I get value undefinded

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on Angular4. I have something that I don't undestand.
I store a value on the service provider and then I get it from a component.
This is my code:

gard service provider:

```
key:any;
constructor(){}
    storeKeysAppPreferences(res){
            this.appPreferences.clearAll();
            console.log("storeKeysAppPreferences",res);
            this.appPreferences.store('key1',JSON.stringify(res));
        }

        fetchKeysAppPreferences(){
          this.appPreferences.fetch("key1").then(
            (res) => {
                this.key=(JSON.parse(res));
              }
           );
        }
```

When I try `console.log()`

```
fetchKeysAppPreferences(){
  this.appPreferences.fetch("key1").then(
    (res) => {
        this.key.push(JSON.parse(res));
        console.log(this.key); //is definded
      }
   );
   console.log(this.key); // undefined
}
```

the value of key is undefined. Why is that?

Comment: Calm down man, there's no `http` word in it. It could be a custom classe that has the same keywords. OP, what does your `appPreferences` class does ? is it making http calls, or local storage calls, or ... ?

Comment: the app references is basically a file that we store on it data like tokens

Comment: @trichetriche It is a duplicate regardless of whether there is `http` in the code or not. The callback of a promise `then` call is asynchronous by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is async operation you need to do like below:

**Note:** Here it shows just the concept only.Please arrange methods according to your use case.

```
constructor(){}
    storeKeysAppPreferences(res){
            this.appPreferences.clearAll();
            console.log("storeKeysAppPreferences",res);
            this.appPreferences.store('key1',JSON.stringify(res)).then(()=>{//here is the place
                  fetchKeysAppPreferences(){
                      this.appPreferences.fetch("key1").then(
                         (res) => {
                            this.key=(JSON.parse(res));
                          }
                      );
                    }
                    })
          }
```

Comment: The storeKeysAppPreferences and fetchKeysAppPreferences are two separate methods. I call storeKeysAppPreferences on the login page and I call fetchKeysAppPreferences on the homepage. So I can not do it like that

Comment: I just showed the concept only. This seems to be an issue of Async pattern. So I would like to suggest you to send data using `push/setRoot` method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `console.log(this.key); // undefined` inside the callback indeed the second console.log() is executed before the response is ready.

Comment: So I add `setTimeout(function(){ },3000);`  to resolve the problem ?

Comment: Wait, What do you want to do with key property after fetch it?

Comment: I will call the fetch from another component (home page) to test the key. the key represent a tokens.

Comment: Try this: ---> let key: any = fetchKeysAppPreferences(){
          this.appPreferences.fetch("key1").then(
            (res) => {
               return (JSON.parse(res));
              }
           );

Comment: Otherwhise you have to return  this.appPreferences.fetch("key1") from the method and call the .then where you have to use it

Comment: that's I do at the first time